# T-SQL Query for Setting Column Aliases

Tags: sql-server

I'm after a way in SSMS of writing a query that will concatenate Table & Column to give me a much more readable Alias.

I'm actually using SSMS, right clicking on views in the object explorer, and selecting new view.

I select the tables I require from the list of available tables.

I then set the joins required in the SSMS diagram pane, and select all of the columns I want from the various tables.

In the criteria pane, I can see the Column, Alias, and Table columns.
It's fine all the time the value in the Column column is unique, for example:

```
Column = RequestedDeliveryDate
Alias = (blank)
Table = Stock Item
```

BUT!

As soon as the column value is NOT unique, SSMS assigns its own alias, for example:

```
Column = AddressLine1
Alias = Alias1
Table = Customer

Column = AddressLine1
Alias = Alias2
Table = Supplier
```

These are pretty hefty views that I'm dealing with, so SSMS assigns a lot of Aliases, which is not a problem in itself, but makes select statements in my Visual Studio project, much more unreadable:

```
SELECT RequestedDeliveryDate, Alias1, Alias2 FROM vwMyView
```

All that I'm after is some way in SSMS of writing a query that will concatenate Table & Column to give me a much more readable Alias:

```
Column = AddressLine1
Alias = CustomerAddressLine1
Table = Customer

Column = AddressLine1
Alias = SupplierAddressLine1
Table = Supplier
```

This would make my SELECT queries much more readable:

```
SELECT RequestedDeliveryDate,CustomerAddressLine1,SupplierAddressLine1 FROM vwMyView
```

I can manually assign an alias in the Criteria Pane, but it's very tedious across many views with many duplicate column names.

Comment: Why not just write the view yourself? The designer is not going to come up with very meaningful names.

Comment: Yes, this is the limitation you accept when you let the designer do your work for you.   You absolutely SHOULD be doing the tedious chore of choosing your own meaningful names for every column.

Comment: Regardless of whether you are using a designer or tSQL, you will have to type aliases manually. I am not aware of any 3rd party extensions that can do that work for you.

Comment: My view has 20+ tables with over 200 columns. Changing the following is going to mighty tedious with over 20 views to deal with:  
dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode15 AS Expr61, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode16 AS Expr62, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode17 AS Expr63,
dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode18 AS Expr64, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode19 AS Expr65, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode20 AS Expr66

Comment: Ideally (using the first row in the comment above) I want the Alias to be *SLCustomerAccountAnalysisCode15*, rather than *Expr61*

Answer (score 0):

I hate the view designer. Just create the view with code only. Eg:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[MyViewName]
AS

SELECT RequestedDeliveryDate,CustomerAddressLine1,SupplierAddressLine1 FROM vwMyView

GO
```

Copy the joins and filter from the view designer if you like, but then change the field aliasing in the SELECT section.

Comment: But I'm talking about 30-40 views with up to 100 duplicate column names per view. I can't believe that using a query, I can't concatenate table and column name to produce me a readable alias!

Comment: The SQL SELECT for an example view is shown below. As you'll see, I've manually edited the column aliases for the first few fields, but if you look at the end of the SELECT, you'll see that SSMS has named the aliases right up to Alias70. There MUST be some way to create a query that concatenates the table and column names to create the aliases I want!

Comment: SELECT     dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemCode AS SOPOrderReturnLineItemCode, dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine.ItemDescription AS SOPOrderReturnLineItemDescription,
                      dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine.LineQuantity AS SOPOrderReturnLineLineQuantity, dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTypeID AS SOPOrderReturnLineLineTypeID,
                      dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTotalValue AS SOPOrderReturnLineLineTotalValue, dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine.LineTaxValue AS SOPOrderReturnLineLineTaxValue,

Comment: dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode13 AS Expr59, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode14 AS Expr60,
                      dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode15 AS Expr61, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode16 AS Expr62, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode17 AS Expr63,
                      dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode18 AS Expr64, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode19 AS Expr65, dbo.SLCustomerAccount.AnalysisCode20 AS Expr66